# Why isn't the program token recognized? ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4

I have this grammar:

```
    grammar BajaPower;
    
    // Gramaticas
    programa:PROGRAM ID ';' vars* bloque ;
    vars:VAR ((ID|ID',')+ ':' tipo ';')+;
    tipo:(INT|FLOAT);
    bloque:'{' estatuto+ '}';
    estatuto: (asignacion|condicion|escritura);
    asignacion: ID '=' expresion ';';
    condicion: 'if' '(' expresion ')' bloque (';'|'else' bloque ';');
    escritura: 'print' '(' (expresion|STRING ',')* (expresion|STRING) ')' ';';
    expresion: exp ('>'|'<'|'<>') exp;
    exp: (termino ('+'|'-')*|termino);
    termino: (factor ('*'|'/')*|factor);
    factor: ('(' expresion ')')|('+'|'-') varcte| varcte; 
    varcte: (ID|CteI|CteF);
    
    // Tokens
    WS: [\t\r\n]+ -> skip;
    PROGRAM:'program';
    ID:([a-zA-Z]['_'(a-zA-Z0-9)+]*);
    VAR:'var';
    INT:'int';
    FLOAT:'float';
    CteI: ([1-9][0-9]*|'0');
    CteF: [+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+;
    STRING:'"' [a-zA-Z0-9]+ '"';
```

And I'm trying to test it with the following code:

```
       program TestCorrect;
       var
          x,y:int;
          z:float;
       {
          x = 1;
          y = 2;
          z = (x+y*3)/4;
          if (z > x) {
             print("hola mundo",(x+y));
          }
       }
```

When I run it it only detects program as an ID and not the PROGRAM token.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things going wrong. In future, I suggest you incrementally create your grammar instead of (trying) to write the entire thing in one go and then coming to the conclusion it doesn't do what you meant it to.

Let's start with the lexer:

- `WS`: `[\t\r\n]+ -> skip` does not include spaces
- `ID`: `['_'(a-zA-Z0-9)+]*` should be `('_'[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*`
- `ID`: the first part, `[a-zA-Z]`, should probably be `[a-zA-Z]+`
- `VAR`, `INT`, `FLOAT` are placed after `ID`, so when `ID` is properly defined, it will match `var`, `int` and `float` before these tokens
- `CteF`: don't include `[+-]?`, leave that for the parser to deal with
- `STRING`: `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` doe not include spaces, so `"hola mundo"` will not be matched

Now the parser:

- `vars`: `(ID|ID',')+` is wrong because it now always has to end with a comma if you want to match multiple ID's. Do `ID (',' ID)*` instead
- `condicion`: `(';'|'else' bloque ';')` mandates a semi-colon should always be present after an `if` or `else` block, but in your input, you do not have a semi-colon. Do `('else' bloque)?` instead
- `expresion`: `exp ('>'|'<'|'<>') exp` means an expresion always contains one of the operators `>`, `<` or `<>`, which is not correct (an expression can also just be `1*2`). Do `exp (('>'|'<'|'<>') exp)?` instead
- `exp`: `termino ('+'|'-')*` is odd: that will match `1++++++++++++`. Do `termino (('+'|'-') termino)*` instead
- `termino`: `factor ('*'|'/')*` should be `factor (('*'|'/') factor)*` (same as `exp`)
- `varcte`: should probably include `STRING` so that you do not have to do this on multiple places: `(expresion|STRING)` but can then just do `expresion`

All in all, this should do the trick:

```
grammar BajaPower;

programa
 : PROGRAM ID ';' vars* bloque
 ;

vars
 : VAR (ID (',' ID)* ':' tipo ';')+
 ;

tipo
 : INT
 | FLOAT
 ;

bloque
 :'{' estatuto+ '}'
 ;

estatuto
 : asignacion
 | condicion
 | escritura
 ;

asignacion
 : ID '=' expresion ';'
 ;

condicion
 : 'if' '(' expresion ')' bloque ('else' bloque)?
 ;

escritura
 : 'print' '(' (expresion ',')* expresion ')' ';'
 ;

expresion
 : exp (('>'|'<'|'<>') exp)?
 ;

exp
 : termino (('+'|'-') termino)*
 ;

termino
 : factor (('*'|'/') factor)*
 ;

factor
 : '(' expresion ')'
 | ('+'|'-')? varcte
 | STRING
 ;

varcte
 : ID
 | CteI
 | CteF
 ;

WS      : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
PROGRAM : 'program';
VAR     : 'var';
INT     : 'int';
FLOAT   : 'float';
CteI    : [1-9][0-9]* | '0';
CteF    : [0-9]* '.' [0-9]+;
ID      : [a-zA-Z]+ ('_' [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*;
STRING  : '"' .*? '"';
```

[image]